# Regex Match with nested Parens

Tags: java, regex

OK,

I don't know if it is possible to write this regex, so I am going to start by askign for help - so far I have had no success.

source string:

```
,convert(varchar(8000), lt.text) as reason
```

desired match:

```
convert(varchar(8000), lt.text)
```

assumptions

- statement starts with a comma (outside of the parens)
- state will end with "as "

this is the regex i am starting with:

```
\(.+\)
```

Thank you

Comment: What's your platform?  .NET regex has a "balanced grouping" construct that allows you do to this (although you'll still have to deal with escaped parens, if you're concerned about those, in a separate pass).

Comment: JAVA - and I think it is the ensted parens killing me.  I seem to rememebr this not being easy or even possible - but I haven't written regex in a million years..

Comment: It's not possible in "pure" regex, as many people here will tell you.  But I've used said regex extension for just this purpose, and it's great.

Comment: Java's regex engine cannot cope with an arbitrary amount of nesting. From the main stream languages, only Perl, PHP and.NET support recursive matching, AFAIK.

Comment: The expression can be "attached" to the beginning and the end of the string, so I don't see why you should use balancing groups. The comma starts the capture, the last closes parens ends the capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bar Kiers - is correct, the inability to cope "with an arbitrary amount of nesting", is the root cause of both my memory as to why and the reason as to why I couldn't accomplish what I wanted.

HACK ALERT: I solved by grabbing the inner most instance and replacing it out with a placeholder, and then processing recursively until there were no more matches...

Comment: is it possible to post your function? I realize that this is two years after the fact.

Comment: Sorry I am long past that organization.  I believe I created a recursive function (I didn't need to worry about the call stack) where I matched the inner parens, then used the results of that match to as the return from the function where I used it to form a new regex where it was something like expression = '(' + matchFromInnerCall + ')'

Comment: I am sorry looking back I should have posted a solution - but this was a major hack (if I am remembering correctly).

Comment: no worries! I just had a tangential realization about my problem as I was reading your comment so it has been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use following regex :

^\,(?<imp>[\s\S]*?)as

Answer (score 0):

```
^,(.+\)) as [a-z]+$
```

I'm including the "reason" with [a-z]+.

I suggest you use the RightToLeft option, if you have it. It'll speed up the regex. And remember to escape the `\`, if your language require it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming PCRE syntax here.  If you can guarantee that the characters " as " don't show up within the parens, something like this should work:

```
{,(.*) as }
```

If you can't guarantee that " as " won't show up in the parens, you need to define some other conditions that will be met.  For example, if the line always ends after the " as ", something like this would work:

```
{,(.*) as \S+$}
```

Or you could use a real parser, which can keep context (the number of parens).